# ChartJs How to create multiple doughnut chart using loop

Tags: chart.js, donut-chart

I'm attempting to create a doughnut chart using a for loop so that I can generate multiple doughnut charts. The scenario is that I'm sending a list of students (List) to the frontend, and I'm aiming to create a donut chart using the students' names and their respective percentages.

I don't have the exact code, but here's a basic outline:

In my controller:

```
List<Student> listOfStudent = new ArrayList<>();
model.addAttribute("listOfStudent", listOfStudent);
```

And in the JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="student" items="${listOfStudent}">

var ctx = document.getElementById("donutChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["studname1", "studname2", "studname3", "studname4", "studname5", "studname6", "studname7"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#2ecc71",
        "#3498db",
        "#95a5a6",
        "#9b59b6",
        "#f1c40f",
        "#e74c3c",
        "#34495e"
      ],
      data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7]
    }]
  }
});
```

In the labels, the value should be the student's name, in donut there will be student percentage , and below the doughnut, there should be the total number of students.

Attached is the reference image for clarification.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the data from the list of students into the chart. so you need to replace labels and data accordingly.

Comment: Can you please provide me some code snippet

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. As it’s written, your answer doesn’t give enough information that the average reader is going to understand how to use it to solve a similar problem. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details and to clarify your recommendation for the benefit of the community?** Regards.